# Dynamically create numeric matrix from fields of a scalar structure

Tags: matlab, structure

in Matlab, I have a scalar structure `S` with some fields. Each field contains a numeric vector, and all these vectors have the same size, say `nx1`.

Now I would like to create a numeric matrix based on a selection of the fields.

The starting point is a logical mask sized `mx1`, where m is the number of fields of `S`. `mask(i)` is `true` if the ith field of `S` should be included in the matrix. So the matrix size would be `n x sum(mask)`.

Example (in my code, the structure is not built in this way, of course :-)

```
vec = rand(1000,1);
S.f1 = vec;
S.f2 = vec;
S.f3 = vec;
S.f4 = vec;
S.f5 = vec;

mask = [false true true false false]; % 5 elements because S has 5 fields
```

The expected output would be:

```
output = [S.f2 S.f3];
```

But of course, the creation of `output` should depend dynamically on the fields of `S` and on `mask`.

Is there any way to achieve this *without* using an ugly construction including a filter of the struct field names, loop, etc.?

Thank you very much!

Philip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
fns = fieldnames(S) %// Get all fieldnames
S = rmfield(S,fns(~mask)) %// Remove all fields with masking values as false
```

Next, to get your numeric array, use `struct2array` -

```
output = struct2array(S)
```

Comment: That was a nice clean way of doing it =)

Comment: Wow, this solution has it all: Can be written as a 2-liner, and adds no extra memory load since it doesn't need the dummy cell (from struct2cell in the answer of @RobertP.). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the struct into a cell using [`struct2cell`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html), and use normal cell indexing to get the fields you want.

```
a = (1:5).';
s.f1 = a; s.f2 = 2*a; s.f3 = 3*a; s.f4 = 4*a; s.f5 = 5*a;
c = struct2cell(S);
[c{mask}]  
ans =

     2     3
     4     6
     6     9
     8    12
    10    15
```

Comment: Works fine (both with and without `find`). But it adds the detour via struct2cell which is not a disaster, but still inconvenient. I have ~200 structure fields, and each contains an vector of ~1 million elements, so this adds quite some extra load...

Comment: @user986990, I see, I guess it's not a perfect solution for what you want to do, but at least it's simple and very intuitive. For cases with less data I think this is a good solution =)

Comment: I agree, for smaller problems it's definitely a good solution with very few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
msks = fieldnames(S);
msks = msks(mask);
n = numel(msks);
output = zeros(1000,n);
for i = 1:n
    output(:,i) = S.(msks{i});
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works, it actually looks exactly like the code that I am using now. But this is what I meant by "ugly" in my question :-)